# Share session variables with virtual directory (Coldfusion, IIS7)

Tags: session, coldfusion, iis-7, virtual-directory

In IIS7, I created a virtual directory called "logic."  This points to a directory outside the root of the site that contains code that I want to use across multiple sites on the server.  I want some of that code to set variables in the SESSION scope, but it appears that creating a virtual directory has isolated the session variables to the virtual directory.

Is there any way in IIS7 to allow the virtual directory to share the site's SESSION scope?  If not, what's an appropriate alternative?  I know I could pass variables between pages through the URL or FORM scopes, but some of this data being passed includes user data that I don't want someone to spoof by simply passing URL or FORM values.

Comment: Do you happen to have an Application.cfc or Application.cfm with a different application name in the virtual directory? ColdFusion does not set/create sessions/session variables based on directory location - unless there is App.cfc or App.cfm in the directory.

Comment: Are you having the virtual directory setup as a different application as @ScottStroz mentioned? In this case you cannot have those variables in the virtual directory as those are belongs to a different application

Comment: No, the virtual directory does not have it's own app.cfc or app.cfm, nor is there one in any directory above it on the drive.  That was making me think this is either a CF Administrator setting or an IIS7 setting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have a feeling it is a setting somewhere (possibly IIS)  we are now having the same problem but not on all servers

Comment: No, not resolved. We're thinking of a totally new approach since this wasn't working, but I haven't had time to develop it.